# How to increase Bluetooth communication speed in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, low-latency

I have an iOS application which communicates with an BLE device that requires the lowest latency.

The manufacturer of the BLE device specifies that connection interval supported by the device as follows.

```
#define MIN_CONN_INTERVAL               MSEC_TO_UNITS(7.5, UNIT_1_25_MS)             /**< Minimum acceptable connection interval, Connection interval uses 1.25 ms units. */
#define MAX_CONN_INTERVAL               MSEC_TO_UNITS(30, UNIT_1_25_MS)             /**< Maximum acceptable connection interval, Connection interval uses 1.25 ms units. */
```

Manufacture of BLE device ask to usa a minimum connection interval of 11.5ms in the iOS code.

This is the first time I hear about changing connection interval. But after some research, it seems that the device that initiate the connection can request for a better interval.
(https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/6500/not-clear-about-minimum-and-maximum-connection-interval)

However I can't find a way for my iOS Bluetooth manager to ask for a better latency. Is this even possible in iOS?

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that the device is a BLE Midi device. I don't know if that can help for improving the latency.

Sincerely,

Jery

Comment: As far as I know you can't update the connection parameter from the iOS side. But you can from the peripheral side send an L2CAP Connection Parameter Update Request and hope that iOS will accept a lower connection interval. But I don't think they accept anything lower than 30 ms...

Answer (score 1):

Apple only offers Bluetooth LE to developers, which is much slower than standard Bluetooth.

With that said, you can access the faster Bluetooth in iOS by joining the [MFi program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/) and writing Apple a check for the ability to do so.

This section from the MFi FAQ gives some clarification on the issue from Apple:

> I want to develop an accessory that communicates with an Apple device
>   using only Bluetooth Low Energy. Do I need to join the MFi Program?
>   No. Accessories which connect to an Apple device using only Bluetooth
>   Low Energy/BLE/Bluetooth 4.0 or standard Bluetooth profiles supported
>   by iOS are not part of the MFi Program.

So in other words, to use [Bluetooth EDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Bluetooth_2.0_+_EDR), you must join MFi.

Comment: He is trying to connect to an Bluetooth LE device, So ability to use an BR-EDR connection won't have any effect/improvement on this use case.